# not work mousemove & mouseleave in (tilt images)

Tags: javascript, mousemove, mouseleave

I am on tilt (the tilt images)
But does not work
Css and js are gonna attached to the site

view-source:http://tympanus.net/Development/ImageTiltEffect/js/tiltfx.js
view-source:http://tympanus.net/Development/ImageTiltEffect/css/tilteffect.css
and
My html code :

```html
<div class="Testj3_block_content">

<div class="customtilt">
 <div class="tilt__back" dir="ltr" style="background-image: url('/Testj3/images/ImageTiltEffect/3.jpg');">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="tilt__front" style="background-image: url('/Testj3/images/ImageTiltEffect/3.jpg'); opacity: 0.5; transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 0deg);">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="tilt__front" style="background-image: url('/Testj3/images/ImageTiltEffect/3.jpg'); opacity: 0.6; transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 0deg);">&nbsp;</div></div>
</div>
```

The source code
please guide me
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)     // yours, no translation
translate3d(100px, 50px, 50px) // with translation

rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 0)     // yours, no degrees
rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 50deg) // with degrees
```

Your css syntax is is correct, you've just set the transformations to zero pixels and zero degrees.

[Here's the basic documentation for css3 3d transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp) that will help you

Comment: You are right
But this is not my problem.
See : http://tympanus.net/Development/ImageTiltEffect.
My images are fixed and do not move, but move here.
On this website I go to right click - inspect element - in front of the " div class tilt " written ev ، But not on my site.
js does not work.
Excuse me, I speak English very poor

Comment: Can you create a plunker or jsfiddle with your entire code? If you do that we can troubleshoot. Otherwise start over using the tympanus code that works and edit it from there.